# I can not build the generated Android project by Zebble

Tags: xamarin-zebble

I am getting the following error when building the android project generated by Zebble for Xamarin.

I followed the steps in -READ-ME-NOW!!!!!!!!!!!! text file. When I did build the android project, this is error I got:

> The command "Zebble" update-schema auto" exited with code -1.

Some additional error log I found from Build output:

> EXEC : error : Failed to update the xml schema for intellisense: Failed to find the UWP exe file. Searched all EXE files inside: E:\Labs.NET\Xamarin\TestZebble\TestZebbleApp\Run\UWP\bin

Could you please tell me what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

1. Remove all `zebble` folders from nuget `packages` folder.
2. Remove the `Run\Android\Zebble.exe` file.
3. Update the `zebble` nuget to latest version.
4. Set the `Android` project as startup project.
5. From `Build` > `Configuration Manager` be sure that `Build` and `Deploy` are enabled for android project.
6. Rebuild the solution.

Comment: I updated to the latest zebble now. It solved the problem. Thanks.I just need to run the UWP app with emulators and see how it works.